# Right-aligned responsive CSS grid layout

Tags: html, css, layout, grid-layout

I have an HTML layout I need to develop and I can't think of any nice way to do it...

How can I make this layout?

It is basically a normal responsive centred column layout, where the column is a max-width with some padding - I have no problem with that part. However, the part I am having problems with is that there is also a right-aligned column, but the left-hand edge of this is aligned to the left-hand edge of the centred column.

How could I achieve this with CSS, ideally without the use of JavaScript to calculate widths etc.?

(And yes, this has to work in the most recent 2 versions of browsers, so css grid layout etc. probably not going to be useful unfortunately)

Like this:

[image]

Someone asked for code, so here's some pseudo code, however I am asking for ways to do this using HTML and CSS, so this (very basic) code may not be the right way. Nevertheless, here's a very basic column layout with a (non working) right aligned column.

I should perhaps also add that I have a good understanding of HTML and CSS, but cannot think of a way to do this layout. "Use bootstrap" is probably not a helpful answer unfortunately, unless you can show how it can specifically do this (and then I'll copy the styling and do it myself)

```
<style>
.centre-aligned-column {
    max-width: 960px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    margin: auto;
}
.right-aligned-column {
    /* how? */
}
</style>
<section>
    <div class="right-aligned-column">
        RIGHT ALIGNED COLUMN CONTENT
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="centre-aligned-column">
        CENTRE ALIGNED COLUMN CONTENT
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your tag: `grid-layout` already answers your question. There are many ways - but that depends if your app/website is laid out 'small-screen' first and many other things. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kVeCqQCxlk  (ps: it doesn't 'change everything' it just changes a small portion of things)

Comment: You'll have to actually write some code if you want help. : )

Comment: @sheriffderek it is my understanding that grid layout is not well enough supported for production use in this instance but I will look into if I can get away with using it or not. Unfortunately I have not had a lot of experience with it due to its lack of browser support.

I don't see how writing any code helps you answer but I have put some code now.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not been able to find anything in css grid layout that allows me to make two sections, one with a responsive column, and another which starts from the same point as the responsive column at the left, but continues to the right of the page. It appears grid layout is mostly only useful for single grids, not for multiple sections (which will have different background styling and so forth). Am I missing something?

Comment: Watch the video dude... try a few more times. You are really phoning it in. "I don't see how writing any code helps you answer..." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here is a starting point: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/vpd3u77u/

Comment: Yes, I am still looking into it - though I have not yet found a way or seen an example that does what I want. Can css grid do consistent grid layouts in different areas? The actual required solution is far more complex than my mockup above, and is more like this:
centred layout
different layout
another layout
yet another layout
right aligned layout
centred layout
a different layout again
right aligned layout

...etc

Also thanks for the fiddle, but as you can see, the left columns do not align in your fiddle - which is exactly the issue I am trying to correct.

Comment: My point is - I did the work - to show the problem, which is what you should do - before asking the question. I hope you can understand the point.

Comment: I also did the work to show the problem - see the image I uploaded. I am asking for how to do this, not how to fix my current code. I am sorry if that was not clear.

So to clarify: Does anyone know a way, theoretical or actual code samples, to achieve what I am trying to do (in a way that works in all browsers, and ideally not using JavaScript)?

Answer (score -1):

You can use bootstrap for grid system. It is responsive already and you only have to call the classes for specific width. See this reference link https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp.

Comment: How can bootstrap do a right-aligned column with its left edge aligned to the same position as a centre-aligned max-width column, and responsively?

I don't believe it can.

Comment: bootstrap calculate same width percentage in every column, then the `row` class or the parent has a margin-left and margin-right negative value so left side of the `row` aligned to left and right side of the `row` aligned to right, I used this grid classes but others are manual coding

Comment: like the the every column of the grid classes has a padding, but the row parent div element left and right has a negative value

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. I dare you to try it.

Comment: I'm relatively familiar with bootstrap. I could be mistaken, but I don't think it can help in this situation. It is good at doing columns, but I don't see that it can help with the right-aligned issue I have.

To do negative values and what not I'd have to use JavaScript to calculate it, which is an option but one that I am trying to avoid.